# Fusuma gestures not executed

Tags: command-line, touchpad, multi-touch, gestures

I run fusuma on startup but it doesn't seem to work most of the times.
If I open a terminal and run fusuma and do the mouse pad gestures the terminal shows that the gestures are recognized but not executed. If I press super + Left for example it moves the window to the left half but if I do it with the gestures it won't work, even if I can see in the terminal that the gesture is recognized

Answer (score 0):

I would be of a greater help if you could include screenshots of the output of fusuma in the terminal, because the only thing I can think of without seeing what the output is the following answer:

If you're mapping your gestures, you are either using one of these two ways to map them.

1. You are creating the configuration file `~/.config/fusuma/config.yml` and mapping the gestures there.
2. You are editing the configuration file `config.yml` located in various subdirectories under `/var/lib/gems` and mapping the gestures there.

**Either of these is technically okay to use, but in my case the first option didn't work.** So to find the file path of the second option, I performed a search for "config.yml" under `/var/lib/gems`. For me, I found it at `/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/fusuma-2.1.0/lib/fusuma/config.yml`, but the exact directory names will vary depending on the version of ruby or fusuma you have.

**(You should try doing the first option, and if it doesn't work, then do the second.)**

If you're using the second option, you might have to get root permissions to edit the config file.

**Check this image to see if you are using the same format:**

[image: FORMAT]

***Again, if this doesn't work, you will need to include screenshots of fusuma's terminal output.***